# If a class has style then skip it Javascript loops

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I got an issue in javascript loops. 
I am creating a chrome extension and even i have implement it. first i wanted to run a loop in having gap I did that but now i have an another issue and it drives me crazy. 
I have some Classes And I want to tell my loops that if a class has style in code then skips it from  loops and move on to another. 
my code is. 
I want the loops in Time and i want it to skip those class which has style. 
or if it's not possible then yes i want it to skips those class which has area-pressed= true. 
Here is my code. :D

```js
function nothing(){

var inputs= document.getElementsByClassName('checking');
var get= document.getElementsByClassName('nothing').style;
function doSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() { inputs[i].click(); }, i*1000);
}
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
if ( get == null) {
       doSetTimeout(i);
    }
}
```

```html
     <button onclick="nothing()"> Hey </button>  
    <a href="#" class="checking" area-pressed="false"> Nothing </a>
    <a href="1" class="checking" style="noting"> Nothing </a>
    <a href="3" class="checking"  style=""> Nothing </a>
   <a href="4" class="checking" area-pressed="true"> Nothing </a>
    <a href="5" class="checking" area-pressed="false"> Nothing </a>
```

Comment: Use something other that `style` and you'll be much happier. For example, maybe you can select based on a `data-` attribute or the presence or absence of another class. You can use `querySelectorAll` for this.

Comment: But if you just want to exclude elements that have a `style` attribute, then use this: `var inputs= document.querySelectorAll(".checking:not([style])");`

Comment: It work like a charm. 
Thanks sir (Y)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

try `if (inputs[i].style.<your property> === "<your value>") continue` in your for loop, **before you do anything else**

for example: `if (inputs[i].style.background === "red") continue`

Comment: sir if the style has multi colour i mean if a class has different colour then another and want the color to be any like in your property it should be any color. 
and why not to make it easy. 
I want if a class contain style tag skip it. 
and click on another class. 
that should be easy or if a class has area-pressed = true then skip it else click. 
can you help me in that ? 
Thanks a lot of the quick reply .

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch style of each element in the loop itself using `inputs[i].style` and then check if it is set or not.

```
function nothing() {

  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('checking');

  function doSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      inputs[i].click();
    }, i * 1000);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var style = inputs[i].style;
    if (!style) {
      doSetTimeout(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sir it doesn't work for me. 
can you please check it here. 
[JS Fiddle Link to COde ](https://jsfiddle.net/Hariskhan488/hhjLnjgr/24/)

Comment: @HarisKhan why are you adding `noting` in style? It should be `nothing` and should be a part of class attribute isnt it?